# Counting days left live

Tags: android

I am creating a small app that records what user has in a fridge/freezer.
There is a list of products in a form of a **ListView**, to which user can add new product. When adding new we can pick an **expiry date**, by which app should be able to count how many days left. I have an `adapter` and few `activities`, but not sure if the days count is going to change every day? Is there any other way I can do it? Here's my code:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
/**
 * The name of the food product
 */
private String name;
/**
 * The quantity of product
 */
private int quantity;

private Metrics measure;
/**
 * The expiry date of the product
 */
private Date expiry;
/**
 * The price of the product
 */
private double price;
/**
 * The shelf life of the product
 */
private int shelfLife;
/**
 *
 */
private FoodCategory foodType;

/**
 *
 * @param aName
 * @param aQuantity
 * @param anExpiry
 * @param aPrice
 */
public Product(String aName, int aQuantity, Metrics aMeasure, Date anExpiry, double aPrice, FoodCategory aType)
{
    this.name = aName;
    this.quantity = aQuantity;
    this.measure = aMeasure;
    this.price = aPrice;
    this.expiry = anExpiry;
    this.foodType = aType;
    Date date = new Date();
    this.shelfLife =  (int)(anExpiry.getTime()-date.getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}

/**
 * Returns the name of the product
 *
 * @return    name
 */
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param aName
 */
public void setName(String aName)
{
    this.name = aName;
}
/**
 * Returns the quantity of the product
 * @return quantity
 */
public int getQuantity()
{
    return quantity;
}

public Metrics getMetric()
{
    return measure;
}

/**
 *
 * @param aQuantity
 */
public void setQuantity(int aQuantity)
{
    this.quantity = aQuantity;
}
/**
 * Returns the price of the product
 * @return price
 */
public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

/**
 *
 * @param aPrice
 */
public void setPrice(double aPrice)
{
    this.price = aPrice;
}
/**
 * Returns the number of days of the shelf life of product
 * @return shelfLife
 */
public int getShelfLife()
{
    return shelfLife;
}
/**
 *
 * @return String representation of Product object
 */

public FoodCategory getFoodType()
{
    return foodType;
}

public void setFoodType(FoodCategory aType)
{
    this.foodType = aType;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return name + " " + quantity +  " " + price + " " + expiry + " " + shelfLife;
}

}




 public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<Product> products;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.products = products;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return products.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_product,null);
    }
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    TextView metric = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.metric);
    TextView expiry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expiry);

    Product newProduct = products.get(position);
    name.setText(newProduct.getName());
    int q = newProduct.getQuantity();
    String s = String.valueOf(q);
    quantity.setText(s);
    metric.setText(newProduct.getMetric().toString());
    int d = newProduct.getShelfLife();
    String ss = String.valueOf(d);
    expiry.setText(ss + " day/s left");
    System.getProperty("line.separator");
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: I guess it would be better to save `anExpiry` and calculate actual shelfLife in adapter

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was thinking actually, but is adapter going to change it every day?

Comment: The method `getView` is called everytime you create view. Easiest thing is probably to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in `onResume()`

Comment: Thank you,I didn't know that, I will try this way

Answer (score 0):

This is a general date counter with years, and months. if you want only days, you can omit (year and month) related codes.

```
Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
      thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,25);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,7); // 0-11 so 1 less thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1985);

      Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

      long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
```

Here's an approximation...

```
long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

If you are developing an app in Firebase then let me know.